# How is Triage time limit calculated?

Tags: support, triage

After I review the 20 triage questions, it tells me "Come back in __ hours to review more questions." However, this number has been anywhere from 5 to 11 hours for me. How is that number calculated?

Comment: Have you considered Next Midnight UTC?

Comment: 20 reviews a day.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think it is midnight UTC. I do not live in the UTC timezone, so it did not occur to me.

Comment: @bcdan, heh, I don't live in the "UTC timezone" either. Right now we're UTC+2. At a vaguely specified point in time next fall, we'll be back to UTC+1, and so on and so forth :)

Comment: Take a look at the achievements dropdown, it shows the UTC time.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did not notice the UTC on the achievements. Thanks

Comment: I know I always get a little freaked out when I would see "Come back in 23 hours" :D

Answer (score 7):

A Stack Exchange "Day" starts and ends at UTC midnight, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27201/288751) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199/288751).

The UTC time is displayed in the Achievements Menu

[image]